# Interpreting of hypothesis prediction after reversed relationship

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, interaction

I am currently facing a big issue with regard to my master thesis. I developed following hypotheses:

Hypothesis 1: Managers’ investment in innovation increases when the organization is judged in decline state *(**positive** relationship between organizational decline and investments in innovation)*

Hypothesis 2: The relationship between organizational decline and investments in innovation is **positively** moderated by managerial ownership: Managers’ with higher company ownership will invest more in innovation when the organization is judged in a decline state

Hypothesis 3: The relationship between organizational decline and investments in innovation is **positively** moderated by institutional ownership: Firms with higher institutional ownership will invest more in innovation when the organization is judged in a decline state

Here you can find my conceptual model:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/kvji.png/

This is the outcome of the regression:

$log(Investments in Innovation) = 6.984 - 0.852Decline - 4.703Managerialown + 3.030ManagerialownDecline-1.870Institionalown + 1.14 Institionalown x Decline $

My issue is now at the beginning I predicted a positive moderation in Hypothesis 2 and 3 based on a positive relationship in Hypothesis 1.

Now the return shows that there is a negative relationship in Hypothesis 1 (so managers invest less), yet both moderators Managerialown and Institutionalown mitigate this relationship (so managers invest less at a slower rater with increasing ownership)

Do I confirm my Hypothesis 2 and 3 or reject them? As I understand, a positive moderation intensifies the main effect. However, now the moderator lessens the main effect of Hypothesis 1, yet my second description of the hypotheses is still somehow valid (*Managers’ with higher company ownership will invest more in innovation when the organization is judged in a decline state*)

Thank you very much for your help.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

I think the term "positive moderation" - if it means anything - means that the moderation term has a positive coefficient. You explain what you mean in the second part of H 2 and 3, so I would say you have confirmed them.

I hadn't seen "positive moderation" or "negative moderation" in this sense - I don't think they are used much (probably because of precisely the confusion brought on by the issues you raise).

To confirm this, I first Googled the two words "positive" and "moderation" and I got what I thought I would - lots of articles about moderation in the statistical sense. When I Googled the phrase "positive moderation" however, I got mostly stuff unrelated to statistics.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Do you think it would be perhaps wise to rephrase the second and third hypothesis to a "neutral" statement? e.g. "The relationship between organizational decline and investments in innovation is moderated by managerial ownership: Manager's with higher company ownership will invest more in innovation when the organization is judged in a decline state"

Comment: If your committee lets you rephrase them, yes.

Comment: Well, it is up to my own judgement. So would you agree that the neutral statement is more accurate / more scientific correct? One last thing. I really appreciate your help Peter. Without people like you, lots of students would be lost!

Comment: I would just delete the phrase "positive moderation" and leave the rest.